# Ubuntu gnome takes a long time to log in

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, gnome

I have just installed ubuntu and installed the gnome-desktop. Before I installed the gnome-desktop it didn't take a long time to log in. After I switched to gnome-desktop it took a long time to log in (~30s). So I went to the terminal and entered:

```
dmesg|less
```

The time consuming parts are (actually the last lines):

```
[   15.437509] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: read fault at 0000011000 engine 07 [PBDMA0] client 06 [HOST] reason 00 [PDE] on channel -1 [00ff86f000 unknown]


[   30.438407] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: systemd-logind[2303]: failed to idle channel 2 [systemd-logind[2303]]


[   45.438649] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: systemd-logind[2303]: failed to idle channel 2 [systemd-logind[2303]]
```

I actually don't know a lot about gnome and Linux and general but I think the problem has to do with my GPU. I use an GTX 970, but did not need to install any drivers after the installation of Ubuntu. My ubuntu version is 16.04.

I am thankful for any help.

Comment: Install drivers by `sudo apt install nvidia-367`

Comment: I actually just solved the problem by the following post:

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/600467/blackscreen-failed-to-idle-channel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blackscreen - failed to idle channel](http://askubuntu.com/questions/600467/blackscreen-failed-to-idle-channel)

Comment: This solution does exactly the same.

Comment: I am sorry, I guess someone can just delete my post.